# How to set up an api for the IBM cloud services to access a node-red dashboard

Tags: api, node-red, ibm-appid

I would like to set up a oauth access for a node-red deployed on bluemix and access a multiuser dashboard. I think it should be done via the IBM Cloud Function API and use IBM Cloud App ID to protect it with the IBM Cloud API Gateway- that said - theres no way to connect those gateway functions to the dashboard webpages through bluemix that I can see. Has this use of node-red been done?

Note **I am not** trying to provide access to node-red flows only **secure the Dashboard pages created with the multi-user node**.

I have multi-user multi-sessions dashboard running but theres no current nodes to secure this - or flows that offer this functionality  - I'm not even sure you could build oauth using flows. Perhaps a dedicated node that is built to provide ...perhaps fussing with bluemix-settings.js

I've researched Node-red capacity especially when deployed in IBM cloud and this is adequate. Node-red provides easy to provision cloudant access as well as dashboard functionality that I want to embed in a consumer mobile app.

So the point is to provide oauth for the public access of the dashboard and to protect the cloudant endpoints. As well as keep the functionality in the cloud rather than in the mobile app.

This is preferably a code-less solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information on dashboards? What do you mean by Dashboard pages created with the multi-user node?

There are node-red OAuth2.0 and OIDC plugins that can be integrated into the flows to secure them.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-openid
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-auth-oidc
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-simple-oauth2